# Git repository to production server

Tags: git, gitlab, git-workflow

I'm pretty much new to this git repository management. Even though I participated as a developer I have never managed my own repository with production server. So here is the problem. I have created a server dedicated to keep my all projects repositories with gitlab. Now what I want to know is how to move my master branch code in to production server easily(which in different servers). What is the procedure for do it.

Comment: Don’t use git as a deployment strategy. Instead consider using continuous integration or continuous deployment instead. Using a server for this task allows you to automate your deployments.

Comment: please add more information like, what is a build system do you use, what is the programming language, what is the OS of the target server?

Comment: language is php, os is ubuntu gitlab is the vcontrol platform

Comment: Do you have a solution. I am trying to do the same right now for my VPS.